# Setting up your module with Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci, silverstripe

Anyone got a boilerplate the world can use for Travis CI build testing for modules?

I havn't used Travis CI before but I got it hooked up however all my builds are failing, and the logs just say `phpunit exited with code 1`. I assume I'm definitely missing something and I have a feeling I need to download all silverstripe composer dependecies but have no idea where to start

I'm wanting it to run tests against (mymodule)/tests folder and hoping it's possible

The section on "[Connecting to CI](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/creating-great-open-source-modules?ref=hub)" isn't very helpful!

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `.travis.yml` file?

Comment: Also, your phpunit tests run fine locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set up with travis you'll need to use the [travis-support](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-travis-support) module.

It's quite straightforward to do with a boilerplate .travis.yml which you can see on pretty much any SilverStripe module that's using travis. [Here's a pretty standard one](https://github.com/dhensby/silverstripe-masquerade/blob/582794fa867e367011e51f08489fa50a21d7c11c/.travis.yml).

That file will test against PHP 5.3-5.6 as well as against SilverStripe versions 3.1.x-dev (latest 3.1 development version) all the way to 3.x-dev (3.5 development version).

You'll also need to customise the final line to run the correct test suite.